# Recover Old Versions of VS Projects

Tags: unity-game-engine, version, restore

I am developing a game using Unity3D and am using Prime[31] as my in-app purchase module. The game is being built for the Windows Store (not Windows Phone, yet).

I made a few tweaks to the project unknowingly horribly messing up the IAP. Now, when I request a product purchase, it never seems to go through.

I've scoured my code for the mistake(s) but to no avail; is there any way I can restore the code to the way it was before the change? I know the date on which it was made, and I have the *Visual Studio Project* versions of both the working and non-working game builds.

Any help is very much appreciated.